# Why does jQuery use the prototype property for plugins?

Tags: jquery

One assigns a plugin to the jQuery prototype property. What's the point of doing this when one doesn't use 'new' with jQuery? There's only ever one instance of jQuery isn't there? So couldn't plugins be assigned directly to the singleton jQuery object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plugin methods must be automatically added to each new jQuery object that is created.

`jQuery.fn` is the same as `jQuery.prototype` so assigning a plugin method to `jQuery.fn` is adding it to the jQuery prototype so whenever a new jQuery object is created, that method will automatically be available.  Technically, it's a `jQuery.fn.init` object, but the idea is the same.

Calling jQuery with a string like this:

```
$(".foo")
```

creates a new jQuery.fn.init object which gets its prototype from jQuery.fn (where plug-in methods are defined).

Here's the relevant jQuery code that shows a new object getting created:

```
// Define a local copy of jQuery
var jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
},


// Give the init function the jQuery prototype for later instantiation
jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn;
```

Comment: I must be missing something then. When are new jQuery objects created? I thought there was only one.

Comment: @IanWarburton - I added that to my answer.

Comment: Oh yes I see... $ is a factory method that creates a new jQuery instance.